# VB6 minor subtraction issue

Tags: vb6, ado

I am facing a very little problem but I am totally confused how to resolve it
I have two tables in my access database which have similar items in it from the first table i.e **tbl_reci_inds**
I have selected **reci_prod_code** which is a product code, also in this table this product code is used multiple times for different items  e.g.

```
+----+----------------+-----------+----------+
| ID | reci_prod_code | reci_inde | reci_qty |
+----+----------------+-----------+----------+
| 74 |      123518233 | hello     |       15 |
| 75 |      123518233 | New Item  |       80 |
| 77 |      123518233 | Egg       |        1 |
+----+----------------+-----------+----------+
```

Now I want to select each item from this table having same prod_code and remove its quantity from the second table which is basically used for stocks the stock table is **tblCafe**

```
+---------+-----------+----------+
| Item_id | Item_name | Item_qty |
+---------+-----------+----------+
|       1 | hello     |      425 |
|       2 | New Item  |      500 |
|       3 | Egg       |     1000 |
+---------+-----------+----------+
```

Now the thing is when I select  product number  **1001** and put its quantity e.g. 2
It should select every item from table 1 and multiple the usage which makes **2xqty** and then subtract the answer from table 2 which is stock
My code looks fine but the only problem I am facing is it only subtracts the first item from the table2 It may be because of query statements and close connections but please and verify what I am doing wrong and how can I resolve this 
Here is my code

```
If Text3.Text = "Café Items" Then
If rs.State = 1 Then rs.Close
sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_reci_inds WHERE reci_prod_code = '" & Text1.Text & "'"
rs.Open sql, cn
With rs
Dim my_prod As String
myprod = !reci_prod_code
Do Until .EOF
If Text1.Text = myprod Then
            Dim final_prod As String
            Dim final_qty As String
            final_prod = !reci_inde
            final_qty = Val(Text5.Text) * Val(!reci_qty)
            sql = "SELECT * FROM tblCafe WHERE Item_name = '" & final_prod & "'"
            rs.Execute sql

            With rs
            .Update
            !Item_qty = Val(!Item_qty) - final_qty
            .Update
            End With
End If
                .MoveNext
            Loop
End With
End If
```

Comment: seems that you are taking final_qty As String might taking Dim final_qty As int/float would resolve your problem

Comment: You need two recordsets - you cannot mix then in the same object.